# The Xpath path contains the HTMLUNKNOWNELEMENT DOM node, which failed to resolve by JS

Tags: javascript, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMO6U.png)
As shown, the DOM node in question is checked in the box, and the Xpath is copied using Chrome's copy function to get the result:” HTML body IMGSRC = “HTTPS:/Form”, and the result is incorrect using the XPathEvaluator.evaluate () method

I tried to ignore the HTMLLUNKNOWNELEMENT DOM node and continue with xpathevaluator. Evaluate () to parse, no effect. Since this is a third-party site, there is no way to modify the DOM structure directly. Is there a general solution to this problem?